# not able to submit post variable through jquery with input as image

Tags: php, html, jquery-plugins

i want to write a plugin which will pass a variable stored as input(which is an image) id to the form on clicking the input image or by any other method

=========================================================================================

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id'];
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Kunfu Panda</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="projection,screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" >
        <form action="panda.php" method="post" class="openid_provider" />
             <input type="image" src="images/google_button.png" id="google" /> 
         </form>    
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').openid(); 
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

===============================================================================

my plugin is openid (test,js)

```
(function($){
    $.fn.openid = function() {
        $('input').click(function(){
        var provider = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).submit(provider);   
        })
        }
})(jQuery);
```

now the form is getting submitted on click on google image which is an input with id "google"  but the form action which is the same page is not able to recognise the $_POST['provider'] variable

please help me out.

Comment: there are a number of mistakes in your html/js sample:

Comment: 1) you have JQueryUI but dont have JQuery, 2) your test.js must be loaded after JQuery 3) calling submit on wrong element and 4) can't pass 'provider' to submit(), 5) image input doesnt have 'name' attribute and 6) posting an image input will only give you xy-coordinates where user clicked on image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
  var_dump($_POST);
?>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Kunfu Panda</title>
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="projection,screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper" >
    <form action="panda.php" method="post" class="openid_provider" />
      <input type="image" src="images/google_button.png" id="google"/> 
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').openid(); 
  })
</script>
```

js:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.openid = function() {
    $('input').click(function(e){
      var provider = $(this).attr('id');  //get id
      var myinput = $('<input type="hidden" name="provider"/>').val(provider);
      $('form').append(myinput);
      $('form').submit();
    })
  }
})(jQuery);
```